# Chaining Twitter Bootstrap modal('hide') with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm displaying a simple Bootstrap modal with a 'checkout' button at the bottom.

On clicking the button I want to:

1. Close the modal, e.g. $('#myModal').modal('hide')
2. Wait until the animation is finished
3. Change window.location.href to my 'checkout'
   page.

I can't seem to find a way of chaining without it instantly running the next function, e.g.

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide').each(function() {
    window.location.href = '/checkout'; 
});
```

or I thought delay() might help, e.g.

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide').delay(1000).each(function() {
    window.location.href = '/checkout'; 
});
```

That doesn't work either it just changes page instantly.

Is this a common jQuery issue?  Or will I have to extend Bootstrap to handle this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an event called `hidden` when twitter bootstrap modal is completely hidden. So you can do something like this:

```
$('#myModal').bind('hidden', function(){
    window.location.href = '/checkout';
}).modal('hide');
```

Comment: I wanted to add this in answer. You can use `one` instead of `bind`. So your function will be executed only **once** right after your following hide method call. And yes, you should run whole this code on checkout button click.

Comment: Thanks, I tried as above and it worked.  I was hesitant at first as I thought the scope might apply to all modal closes, not just the clicking of the 'checkout' button, but it works perfectly!

Comment: If you are looking for exact same behaviour in Bootstrap 3, use "hidden.bs.modal" event instead of "hidden".